# Cannot convert return expression of type 'NodeType.NodeType?' to return type 'NodeType?'

Tags: swift, abstract-class, swift-protocols

I have been dealing with this problem in Swift for a while, tried type erasure and all kinds of stuff, but to no avail; and the problem seems to be common sense (at least to me). How can I emulate abstract class in Swift? In other words, how to make this work:

```
import Foundation

protocol NodeProtocol
{
    associatedtype NodeType
    func getNode() -> NodeType
}

class Node: NodeProtocol
{
    typealias NodeType = Node
    var next:Node = Node()
    func getNode() -> Node {
        return next
    }
}

class AbstractGraph<NodeType:NodeProtocol>
{
    var root: NodeType?
    func getRoot () -> NodeType?{ 
    return root?.getNode()  
    }
}
```

Note: this is just some random code I wrote, just to get to the core of the problem.

Comment: Which lines gives you that error? The `getRoot`?

Comment: is the compiler suggestion sufficient to fix your error? as in `func getRoot () -> NodeType? { return root?.getNode() as? NodeType }`

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, yes, the getRoot () gives that error (specifically the return in that function). Downcasting to a subclass gives nil in Swift, as far as I know, so I am unsure if that is a feasible option, as I intend to use subclasses of Node.

Comment: @sam I was thinking and I have a solution based on your own work. Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898750/2857130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly (you actually ask a couple) but here's the way I 'emulate' abstract classes in **Swift (4)**:

```
protocol Node {
    func getNext() -> Node
}

extension Node {

    func getNext() -> Node {
        fatalError("getNext is not implemented!")
    }

}


struct StringNode: Node {
    var data: String!
}

let sNode = StringNode(data: "test-node-1")

sNode.getNext()
```

Using an extension on the protocol I decide which functions **need** to be implemented by using a fatalError() call.

Now every Node descendant of `Node` *must* implement getNext() otherwise we crash. Run the above code in a playground and you will see that it will crash on the last line, forcing you to implement getNext().

The 'fix' would be:

```
protocol Node {
    func getNext() -> Node
}

extension Node {

    func getNext() -> Node {
        fatalError("getNext is not implemented!")
    }

}


struct StringNode: Node {
    var data: String!

    func getNext() -> Node {
        return StringNode(data: "test-node-2")
    }
}

let sNode = StringNode(data: "test-node-1")

sNode.getNext()
```

And now it won't crash on the last line. All tested in playgrounds using Xcode 9 and Swift 4.

Note: this is not the best implementation of this `Node` protocol ofcourse. The protocol should list operable methods which should denote a `Node` called something like `NodeOperatable`. A class called `Node` should be created implementing this `NodeOperatable` and not implementing the `getNext()` which will force descendant classes to implement the `getNext()`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't trying out protocol extensions!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class AbstractGraph<T: NodeProtocol> {
    var root: T?

    func getRoot () -> T.NodeType? {
        return root?.getNode()
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter what you call the type. In the above I've named it `T`. In yours, you have named it `NodeType` as in:

```
class AbstractGraph<NodeType: NodeProtocol>
```

But reusing `NodeType` as a type name was just kind of confusing with the `associatedtype NodeType` name in `NodeProtocol` that one would expect both to be same but they're actually not.

Basically your `AbstractGraph` requires a type, say `T`, that conforms to `NodeProtocol`.
Since this type `T` conforms to `NodeProtocol`, it automatically has a `NodeType` property in it.
Furthermore, `getNode()` as per the protocol requirements is to return this `NodeType` property.
Hence in `getRoot()` since you are basically returning what `getNode()` is returning, you are required to return the type `T`'s `NodeType` property, not the type `T` itself.